# Redirect non www to www using redirection plugin regex

Tags: regex

I have a scenario where I can't get access to the .htaccess file (no ftp/ssh ) so im relying on the Redirection plugin to redirect.

I have an issue where i need to redirect non-www to www, while preserving the full URL.

example:

```
http://example.com/any-page/
```

redirects to

```
http://www.example.com/any-page/
```

any help is appreciated.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should try changing your WordPress Site URL from Non WWW to WWW (Eg. if your site url is http://example.com then you should edit it from Setting > General > WordPress URL to http://www.example.com I think this will solve your problem.